# Including jsp in jsf gives exception as Input length = 1

Tags: jsp, exception, jsf-2, blob

I have below code in jsp

### myDisplayImage.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
        <%@ page import="java.io.*"%>
        <%
                Blob image = null;
                Connection con = null;
                byte[] imgData = null;
                Statement stmt = null;
                ResultSet rs = null;
                try {
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/mySacDB", "root", "root");
                    stmt = con.createStatement();
                    rs = stmt.executeQuery("select photo from personalInfo where userid = 5");
                    if (rs.next()) {
                        image = rs.getBlob(1);
                        imgData = image.getBytes(1, (int) image.length());
                    }
                    // display the image
                    response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
                    OutputStream o = response.getOutputStream();
                    o.write(imgData);
                    o.flush();
                    o.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    out.println("Unable To Display image<br /><br />");
                    out.println("Image Display Error=" + e.getMessage());
                    return;
                } finally {
                    try {
                        rs.close();
                        stmt.close();
                        con.close();
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

By use of this, image get displayed properly.

However when I include the same page in JSF 2.0 page, I get exception.

```
<o:resourceInclude path="myDisplayImage.jsp"/>
```

Note : `o = xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"`

Exception I get is `Input length = 1`. Stacktrace is

```
 java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:260)
at java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder.decode(CharsetDecoder.java:781)
at com.sun.faces.application.ByteArrayWebOutputStream.writeTo(ByteArrayWebOutputStream.java:112)
at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerResponseWrapper.flushToWriter(ViewHandlerResponseWrapper.java:162)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:264)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:809)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:671)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:626)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:556)
at org.omnifaces.component.output.ResourceInclude.encodeBegin(ResourceInclude.java:79)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1755)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:349)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at com.sac.filter.MyFilter.doFilter(MyFilter.java:48)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

---

### Edit 1

I also tried with new code using `getBinaryStream` still same error. Code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
        <%@ page import="java.io.*"%>
        <%
            Blob image = null;
            Connection con = null;
            byte[] imgData = null;
            Statement stmt = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/mySacDB", "root", "root");
                stmt = con.createStatement();
                rs = stmt.executeQuery("select photo from personalInfo where userid = 5");
                if (rs.next()) {
                    String imgLen = rs.getString(1);
                    System.out.println(imgLen.length());
                    int len = imgLen.length();
                    byte[] rb = new byte[len];
                    InputStream readImg = rs.getBinaryStream(1);
                    int index = readImg.read(rb, 0, len);
                    System.out.println("index----------------" + index);
                    response.reset();
                    response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(len));
                    String tempString = "image/jpeg";
                    String tempExtenson = tempString.substring(tempString.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, tempString.length());
                    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline;filename=/file." + tempExtenson);
                    response.setContentType(tempString);
                    response.getOutputStream().write(rb, 0, len);
                    response.getOutputStream().flush();
                }
                stmt.close();
                // display the image
            } catch (Exception e) {
                out.println("Unable To Display image<br /><br />");
                out.println("Image Display Error=" + e.getMessage());
                return;
            } finally {
                try {
                    rs.close();
                    stmt.close();
                    con.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You shouldn't change the content type in the middle of responding a request. In your case, you want to make this (or other) JSP file dedicated for the sole purpose of outputing the image with the proper content type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't include in your XHTML a JSP that outputs something other than text.

The problem is that your JSP is mixing output of an image to the entire request, setting the content type as `"image/jpeg"` (or outputs `"text/html"` when some error occurs). You won't be able to include it in another request as it is.

In your case, you probably want to just remove all HTML tags and make the JSP just output the image. Then you would be able to show the image properly using plain HTML, like this:

```
<img src="myDisplayImage.jsp" />
```