# how to send dynamic image as part of servletoutputstream in weblogic12c

Tags: java, servlets, weblogic12c

I have to send dynamic image generated through BufferedImage and imageIO.write. The byteArray is written to servletoutputstream of httpsevletresponse. The content-type is set to image/jpeg and encoding is set to utf-8 in httpsevletresponse object.

But while sevletOutputStream.write(b), I am getting java.nio.charset.MalFormedInputException : Input length :1

Do I need to set the encoding to utf-16.

This error is coming in weblogic 12c server with jdk 1.7.0_45 only.

The Same code is working on other application server as well as tomcat

StackTrace : The exception trace as per below

```
<captchaBytes=[B@26e5c86e>  
  java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1> 
<at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:277)> 
<at weblogic.servlet.internal.CharChunkOutput.write(CharChunkOutput.java:116)>
<at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutputWrapper.write(ChunkOutputWrapper.java:148)>
<at weblogic.servlet.jsp.BodyOutputStream.write(NestedBodyResponse.java:54)>
<at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:75)>
```

Code Snippet :

```
Byte[] imageBytes = get image byte from backend using ImageIO.write
httpServletResponse.setContentType("image/jpeg");
ServletOutputStream out;
httpServletResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
httpServletResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
httpServletResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
httpServletResponse.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
out = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();
out.flush();
out.write(imageBytes);  \\ Error Occured here
```

Comment: Without source code and stacktrace it is impossible to guess what is happening.

Comment: Added Stacktrace and code

Comment: In this case I would prefer complete stacktrace, this is very short. btw it makes no sense to set character encoding when you pass binary data.

Comment: This I am calling from a test web application. Before this we have only my local file name.

Comment: Try to comment out setCharacterEncoding() and move flush() after write. I suspect that weblogic thinks that it is character stream encoded with UTF and it fails to convert binary data to UTF character.

Comment: As suggested setCharacterEncoding() was removed and not require. flush() I have move after write.

Answer (score 0):

After adding `httpServletRequest.resetBuffer()` before calling the `out = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream()` resolved this issue. The `MalformedInputException` was thrown because this JSP where image was generated was included as part of other jsp within the image tag src.

Comment: Do you mean that somebody else has already written to output? Some filter or otherservlet that dispatched to this servlet?

Comment: yes. The same code is mentioned in this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11669898/including-jsp-in-jsf-gives-exception-as-input-length-1